# match column from one worksheet to another, and put a 1 under the matched column

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 worksheet. In worksheet it listed in separate columns skills a person has

[image: Worksheet1]

I now want to transfer it into another format.where I have listed all available skills, whenever there's a matched skills from worksheet1 to worksheet2, there should be a 1 output to corresponding worksheet2 columns. 
[image: Worksheet2]

Can anyone help me do that?

Comment: Can you post some images or upload a worksheet for better understanding of the question....?

Comment: I have added pictures, please take a look

Comment: As Skills do you have only five columns of data for the first image??I can only assist in English formulas if this is fine....

Comment: Hi Vasim, it's 6 column of data for 1st image and english formula is alright, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot table can solve the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both of your worksheets start from `A1`...

`Sheet2` = `D2` formula would be

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100,Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$E$1:$E$100,sheet2!D$1,Sheet1!$F$1:$F$100,sheet2!D$1,Sheet1!$G$1:$G$100,sheet2!D$1,Sheet1!$H$1:$H$100,sheet2!D$1,Sheet1!$I$1:$I$100,sheet2!D$1,Sheet1!$J$1:$J$100,sheet2!D$1)
```

Change ranges according to your requirement, Do take care of the freezing `$ sign` within the ranges.....once done...drag your formula across and below..

How does Countifs work:

```
=COUNTIFS(range1,value to find within range1,range2,value to find within range2, range3, value to find within range3.......so on)
```

Comment: Which part you didnt get??